# Access Array from javascript to jinja

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, jinja2

how do i read an array from javascript to jinja template:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

    var x =0;
    function ActionDeterminator() {
    x=x+1;
         document.getElementById("me").innerHTML=x;
         var $label = $('input[id = optionD]').next();
    $label.text(x); 
         alert('{{option_D[0]}}');
        return true;
        }
    </script>>
```

when i use the code above.. it works pretty well.but when i want to put the variable x like this:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

var x =0;
function ActionDeterminator() {
x=x+1;
     document.getElementById("me").innerHTML=x;
     var $label = $('input[id = optionD]').next();
$label.text(x); 
     alert('{{option_D[x]}}');
    return true;
    }
</script>>
```

i get an empty alert dialog. can anyone tell me hw to fix this pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to realize that in `'{{option_D[x]}}'`, the entire expression is being evaluated by Jinja, before it ever gets to the browser, and Jinja knows nothing about what `x` is.

Instead, you should get Jinja output the entire list as a JS array, and then get the Javascript to do the element selection:

```
alert({{ option_D }}[x]);
```

You will probably need to convert `option_D` to JSON at the server side before sending it to the template for this to work.